# ffmpeg how do I get the duration onto the node.js?

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Ok I know how to get the duration of a video in ffmpeg using this command

```
ffmpeg -i ./output/sample.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

I run this command through a function in node but this outputs the duration onto the console, how do I get it onto node.js where I need it?

Comment: What does your nodejs code look like ?

Comment: I have a package that runs console commands for me. It looks like this 
let getDuration = () => { cmd.run('ffmpeg -i ./output/trying.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d \' \' -f 4 | sed s/,//')}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a way to read console output stream, but I would prefer to use **fluent-ffmpeg**: https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

It is a npm module for nodejs.

From here you can call ffprobe (a tool shipped with ffmpeg and better than ffmpeg to get informations about a video), like this:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.ffprobe('./input.mp4', function(err, metadata) {
    //console.dir(metadata); // all metadata
    console.log(metadata.format.duration);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg');

app.get('/getVideoDuration', (req, res) => {
  fs.unlink('public/output.mp4')
  try {
    new ffmpeg('public/input.mov', function (err, video) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(video.metadata.duration.seconds, "video")
            res.send({
              'msg': "Success",
              'duration': video.metadata.duration.seconds
            })
          }

    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.code);
    console.log(e.msg);
  }

})
```