# ffmpeg: check video folder conformance with bash file

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

I wrote a small bash file that reads a folder, generates a playlist, concatenates, adds a logo and encode the big video result for dash ready, i would like to implement it by checking before all videos conformance: if they have same fps, same resolution, same time base etc.
Below my situation:

```
#!/bin/bash
# CONCAT DEMUXER
#This demuxer reads a list of #files and other directives from a text file and demuxes them one after the other, as if #all their packets had been muxed together. All files must have the same streams (same #codecs, same time base, etc.) but can be wrapped in different container formats.

times=()
for f in *.mp4; do
    _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    times+=("$_t")
done
TOTALDURATION=$( echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc )


printf "file '%s'\n" *.mp4 > playlist.txt
ffmpeg -auto_convert 1 -f concat -safe 0 -i playlist.txt -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts 'keyint=50:min-keyint=50:no-scenecut' -r 25 -b:v 2400k -maxrate 2400k -bufsize 1200k -vf "scale=-1:432" -vf "movie=stable.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" -t $TOTALDURATION out.mp4
#clear
echo “VIDEO CONCAT COMPLETED”
```

For example below i find this bash that calculate the total duration in second of the videos of the folder

```
times=()
for f in *.mp4; do
    _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    times+=("$_t")
done
TOTALDURATION=$( echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc )
```

I wish to check if the videos have the same fps, and same resolution before process
Thanks
Massimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Bash

Someone posted in this question an example to get the duration of a video:
[ffmpeg how do I get the duration onto the node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219003/ffmpeg-how-do-i-get-the-duration-onto-the-node-js)

His approach is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,//
```

In my opinion you should use *ffprobe* instead of *ffmpeg*. Much better syntax:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

Good examples can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips

You can save the result of the first video in a variable and compare all other videos with the first one.
Can give you more examples if needed.

But I can recommend another way: **nodejs**

### NodeJS

If you are familiar with JavaScript, just write a NodeJS script. Code is easier to write in my opinion.

You need to install NodeJS. In your project install fluent-ffmpeg with `npm install --save fluent-ffmpeg`.

https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg

Write your script in a js-file of your choice and run your script from your bash script with `node script.js`.

The snippet to find the needed information from your video files can look like this:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg.ffprobe('./input.mp4', function(err, metadata) {
    //console.dir(metadata); // all metadata
    console.log(metadata.format.duration);
    console.log(metadata.streams[0].width);
    console.log(metadata.streams[0].height);
    console.log(metadata.streams[0].r_frame_rate);
    console.log(metadata.streams[0].time_base);
    //... use first console.dir to get all possible informations
});
```

### UPDATE BASH

Here a complete example to convert all mp4 videos in a directory to an *output* directory and concatenate them after:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCALE="768:432"
FPS="25"

mkdir -p ./output/

for i in *.mp4;
  do name=`echo $i | cut -d'.' -f1`;
  echo $name;
  ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -vf scale=$SCALE -framerate $FPS -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f mp4 "output/${name}.mp4";
done

printf "file '%s'\n" ./output/*.mp4 > ./playlist.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i ./playlist.txt -c copy ./output/concat.mp4
```

- width, height and framerate are set to a defined value to make concatenation possible
- preset for video encode is *slow*, so reencode is really slow ;)
- audio bitrate can be increased if necessary, for example to 192k

Comment: Thanks Uwe, i hear about node.js many times but i never study it, as you know I would like to integrate in a bash file all the necessary operations to get a videos concat ready to be dash, but I have first of all problems about audio video sync: because not all videos have the audio track as long as the video, i use cut them with -t on ffmpeg to make it finish with an i-frame but if there are more than one video with this problem concat together arise the glitch of the audio video sync, i hope to explain my self.. for this reason i think to leave the intent for now, too hard to automate for me

Comment: @MassimoVantaggio Don't give up, it's not as hard as you think. No need to verify same parameters, just reencode all of the videos. I posted a complete example bash script, see updated answer. Tested with the two videos you provided, and it works fine. Just run the script in the directory with the input videos and you get a *concat.mp4* in the *output* folder. Reeconding takes some time ...

Comment: You wanted me to learn node.js, as soon as I finished debugging the media server.. Thank you Uwe!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Uwe What you think about? is raw, can be write more in code economy but seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

times=()
fps=()
for f in *.mp4; do

   _t=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration" | grep -o " [0-9:.]*, " | head -n1 | tr ',' ' ' | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }')
    times+=("$_t")

    _f=$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p")
    fps+=(“$_f”)
done

TOTALDURATION=$( echo "${times[@]}" | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc )

tLen=${#fps[@]}

for tLen in "${fps[@]:1}"; do
    if [[ $tLen != ${fps[0]} ]]; then
        printf “WARNING: VIDEO’S FRAME-RATE (fps) ARE NOT EQUALS, THE PROCESS CAN’T START.”
        printf "%s\0" "${fps[@]}" |
            sort -zu |
            xargs -0 printf " %s"
        printf "\n"
       exit 1
    fi
done

for f in *.mp4; do

DUR="$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | sed 's@\..*@@g' | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }')"

FPS="$(ffmpeg -i "$f" 2>&1 | sed -n "s/.*, \(.*\) fp.*/\1/p")"
FPSC=$( echo "($FPS+0.5)/1" | bc )

NAME=$(echo "$f" | cut -d'.' -f1)

GOP="$((FPSC*2))"
DURM="$((DUR%2))"
FDUR="$(($DUR-$DURM))"

ffmpeg -y -i "$f" -i logo.png -c:a aac -b:a 384k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -r $FPSC -b:v 4800k -maxrate 4800k -bufsize 3000k -profile:v main -t $FDUR -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10,scale=1920:1080,setsar=1" ${NAME}-1080.mp4


ffmpeg -y -i ${NAME}-720.mp4 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -async 1 -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=$GOP:min-keyint=$GOP:no-scenecut -bf 0 -s 640x360 -r $FPSC -b:v 800k -maxrate 800k -bufsize 500k -profile:v main -t $FDUR ${NAME}-360.mp4
done

# with a bash for loop
for f in ./*1080.mp4; do echo "file '$f'" >> 1080list.txt; done
# or with printf
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*1080.mp4 > 1080list.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 1080list.txt -c copy 1080set.mp4

# with a bash for loop
for f in ./*360.mp4; do echo "file '$f'" >> 360list.txt; done
# or with printf
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*360.mp4 > 360list.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i 360list.txt -c copy 360set.mp4

rm *1080.mp4
rm *.txt
rm *360.mp4

echo $TOTALDURATION
```

Comment: You should check your script with [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It will help you find issues.

Comment: Thanks i just try it